# HTTP chunked-encoding buffering Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, buffer

Please take a look at the following java Servlet `doGet()` method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");

    int j= 0;
    while(j < 2)
    {   
     String s = "";

     int i = 0;
     while(i<10000)
     {
      s = s + "a";
      i++;
     }

     System.out.println(s.length());
     osw.write(s,0,s.length());
     j++;
    }

    osw.flush();
}
```

Using Tomcat as the Servlet container, the following HTTP response gets generated:

[image]

I'm aware of the fact that `response.getOutputStream()` gives you a reference to
a decorated version of the actual OutputStream of the socket.

Tomcat decorates it in order to handle persistent connections using a chunked-encoding of the HTTP response body.

I wonder why chunks are 2000 hex bytes (8192 dec bytes) it looks like Tomcat always buffers the bytes before sending them to the socket output stream, wich seems to me an inefficient way of doing the job.

In other words, when I make the call:

```
osw.write(s,0,s.length());

where s.lenght() > buffer_size
```

I would expect an HTTP chunk of size `s.lenght()` and not of the dimension of
the buffer Tomcat uses to handle HTTP chunked-encoding.
Hope this is clear.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's inefficient though. If your s.length() was 1 byte every time you wrote something and that resulted in one http chunk - that would be inefficient.

Comment: please note s.length() > buffersize

Comment: Suppose I want to send 16 kb in a single write and buffer size is 8kb (as it is most of the time), it looks like that 16kb have to be copied in the buffer before being sent.Wouldn't it more efficient bypassing the buffer when the amount of bytes to send is > buffer_size ?

Comment: What if there is already data in the buffer? That needs to be written first. At what point is it more efficient to fill the exisiting buffer, write that then write the remainder vs write the existing buffer and then write the new data? If this is the first chunk of response body there are a bunch of headers that need to be sent first. What if the response needs to be compressed? In other words Servlet output is non-trivial and optimisations that work in one case usually break down in another. Trying to figure out the 'right' optimisation add complexity and delay. So containers keep it simple.